# Can a multiclassed bard/druid use the Bardic Inspiration feature while in Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, multi-classing, wild-shape, bard

I’m playing a multiclassed 6th-level bard/2nd-level druid. Could I still use the Bardic Inspiration feature while in Wild Shape?

I looked at the rules; I think technically you can, because all you have to do to use these features is music. So, I can’t see how being a beast would prevent me from just making music by tapping my paws on an object/ground or by using the animal’s cry. Am I correct?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: The related question by you: [Can a Multiclass Bard/Druid use the Cutting Words feature while in Wild Shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165244/can-a-multiclass-bard-druid-use-the-cutting-words-feature-while-in-wild-shape)

Answer (score 16):

## Ask your DM

For the sake of completeness, the relevant part of the Wild Shape feature:

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing so.
>
> — *Player's Handbook*, p. 67

The Bardic inspiration feature you want to retain and so be physically capable of:

> You can inspire others through stirring words or music. To do so, you use a bonus action on your turn to choose one creature other than yourself within 60 feet of you who can hear you.
>
> — *Player's Handbook*, p. 53

Stirring words are probably out, but whether a given beast form is able to perform stirring music is not something addressed by the rules. It is up the good sense of the players (in this case including the DM). Make your case for tapping your paws, or performing some sort of birdsong, to the DM (and the rest of your table). Personally, I would be inclined to allow it for a number of forms — for how [funny it can be](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J---aiyznGQ) if nothing else — but have issues seeing how some, like a snake, would be capable.

Comment: He wasn’t sure either. That’s why I asked. Thanks!!

Comment: The howl of a friendly direwolf can be quite inspiring!